# Stripe Customer Portal - show specific subscription

Tags: stripe-payments

I have one Stripe Customer, that attached to many companies into my project. Every company has its own subscription. So one Customer has many Subscriptions.
But during manage subscriptions on Customer Portal page I want to see just one subscription related to company (for now I see all Subscriptions related to the Customer).

Is there way (param) to show just one subscription related to specific Company (maybe by its ID) on Customer Portal page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible right now to restrict the subscriptions managed in a Customer Portal session. You pass the `customer` [parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customer_portal/sessions/create#create_portal_session-customer) on creation and all subscriptions associated to that Customer object are manageable.