# (re-ask) Only show a part of subscriptions in a customer portal that the backend specifies

Tags: stripe-payments

I have 2 web products A and B, which share one same user database. We offer a paid monthly subscription for A, and a paid monthly subscription for B. Some users have none of them; some users have the subscription for A; some users have the subscription for B; some users have both.

The backend is built with Node.js and the payment is managed by Stripe. In the products, a user can open their customer portal to manage their subscriptions. With the following code, a user X who has both the subscriptions for A and B is able to see the two subscriptions in his customer portal.

```
const portalSession = await stripe.billingPortal.sessions.create({
    customer: customer.id,
});
```

But what we would like to achieve is that, in the product A, the user X can only see his subscription to the product A in his customer portal; in the product B, the user X can only see his subscription to the product B in his customer portal.

Does anyone know if it's possible to achieve this?

(* a related question asked 18 months ago: [Stripe Customer Portal - show specific subscription](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72543418/stripe-customer-portal-show-specific-subscription) *)

Answer (score 0):

In your case it's best to keep those Subscriptions attached to 2 separate Customer objects. You can then map it to the same persona/user in your own database. Otherwise, it's not possible to only show a subset of Customer Subscriptions in a Customer Portal Session.